# How is StreetDirectory.com web map application developed?

Tags: web-mapping, api

I wonder can you tell me how is developed map application like on this site? http://www.streetdirectory.com

What API is used?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the Streetdirectory API

*"The easiest way to start learning about the SD Maps API is to see a simple example. The following web page displays a map centered on Streetdirectory Singapore Office, 305 Alexandra Road, Vantage Automotive Centre, Singapore 159942: "*

Simple Map

http://www.streetdirectory.com/api/developer/docs/examples/map-simple.html

Note: This is SD Map API which similar to Google Map API:

http://www.streetdirectory.com/api/developer/docs/